# Add conditional infinite scroll support on Wordpress and Woocommerce pages

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, conditional-statements, infinite-scroll

I am trying to add jetpack infinite scroll support with different settings to different pages on my Wordpress site. For instance I want the blog page to reload 12 articles every time your scroll down, and I want the shop page to reload 20 products every time. So I tried to do this, but it is not working, somehow the conditions are just being ignored.

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

```
function quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init() {
    if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_category() ) {
        add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
            'type'           => 'scroll',
            'container'      => 'content',
            'wrapper'        => false,
            'render'         => 'render',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
        ) );    } elseif ( is_shop() ) {        
         add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
            'type'           => 'scroll',
            'container'      => 'main',
            'wrapper'        => false,
            'render'         => 'render',
            'posts_per_page' => 20,
        ) );
    } else {        remove_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll','' );
    } }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_theme_infinite_scroll_settings( $args ) {
    if ( is_array( $args ) && is_shop() )
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 20;
         return $args;
}
add_filter( 'infinite_scroll_settings', 'my_theme_infinite_scroll_settings' );
```

Comment: this code just remove infinite-scroll support everywhere, that's not what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Hey Sharif thanks for your help the code you gave me work to enable and disable infinite scroll support but that not what I am trying to achieve, I would like to enable different "infinite srcoll" settings on different pages. (is_home) should have 'posts_per_page' => 12, and (is_shop) should have 'posts_per_page' => 20,  do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I posted another way that I thought would work but not much luck there either, what do you think?

Comment: helpful links
 https://themeshaper.com/2013/10/08/how-to-override-jetpack-infinite-scroll-settings-in-a-child-theme/

https://developer.jetpack.com/hooks/infinite_scroll_settings/

https://developer.jetpack.com/module/infinite-scroll/

Please if it works let me know and mark this answer as correct.